# Python parameters from blender

Tags: python, command-line

How can I pass parameters in python from blender?. I'm try this, but don't work

```
blender -b file.blend -P file.py "param1" "param2"
```

Answer (score 1):

This work

Line command

```
blender -b file.blend -P file.py -- "param1" "param2"
```

file.py

```
for i in range(6, len(sys.argv)):
    print(sys.argv[i])
```